# GPUImage glsl sine wave photoshop effect

Tags: ios, glsl, gpuimage, trigonometry

I have a requirement to implement an iOS UIImage filter / effect which is a copy of Photoshop's Distort Wave effect.  The wave has to have multiple generators and repeat in a tight pattern within a CGRect.

Photos of steps are attached.

[image: original, before effect]

[image: photoshop effect parameters]

[image: after processing, without edge smoothing]

I'm having problems creating the glsl code to reproduce the sine wave pattern.  I'm also trying to smooth the edge of the effect so that the transition to the area outside the rect is not so abrupt.

I found some WebGL code that produces a water ripple.  The waves produced before the center point look close to what I need, but I can't seem to get the math right to remove the water ripple (at center point) and just keep the repeating sine pattern before it:

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 uniform highp float time;
 uniform highp vec2 center;
 uniform highp float angle;

 void main() {
     highp vec2 cPos = -1.0 + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / center.xy;
     highp float cLength = length(cPos);

     highp vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/center.xy+(cPos/cLength)*cos(cLength*12.0-time*4.0)*0.03;
     highp vec3 col = texture2D(inputImageTexture,uv).xyz;

     gl_FragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
 }
```

I have to process two Rect areas, one at top and one at the bottom.  So being able to process two Rect areas in one pass would be ideal.  Plus the edge smoothing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've handled this in the past by generating an offset table on the CPU and uploading it as an input texture. So on the CPU, I'd do something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
{
    table [ i ].x = amplitude * sin (i * frequency * 2.0 * M_PI / tableSize + phase);
    table [ i ].y = 0.0;
}
```

You may need to add in more sine waves if you have multiple "generators". Also, note that the above code offsets the x coordinate of each pixel. You could do Y instead, or both, depending on what you need.

Then in the glsl, I'd use that table as an offset for sampling. So it would be something like this:

```
uniform sampler2DRect table;
uniform sampler2DRect inputImage;

//... rest of your code ...

// Get the offset from the table
vec2 coord = glTexCoord [ 0 ].xy;
vec2 newCoord = coord + texture2DRect (table, coord);

// Sample the input image at the offset coordinate
gl_FragColor = texture2DRect (inputImage, newCoord);
```